# Updating multiple Single column out of many

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to the MoongoDB, so I don't know many things on it. I'm using studio 3T . I created a collection and given all access.

My current scenario is I have big data. I imported the 2M records with only 5 fields.
_id
Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D

Now what I want to do is update 100K data on this big DB collection, for this I have another CSV(CSV2) with two fields _id & Column A
If _id matches update Column A with CSV2 data and keep all fields intact(same)

If I import CSV2 over big data, what it is doing is overriding all 5 column with new CSV data.

Is there any way to perform this task in MongoDB using Studio3T or any other software ?

Thanks & Regards
Kishan

I have tried many options in it... but no effect.
I can write a code for 1 update in mysql but updating 100K data is not possible there. that is why I installed MongoDB thinking this is easier on it

Answer (score 0):

[mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) with `merge` option will help you to achieve your expected result.

> With --mode merge, mongoimport enables you to merge fields from a new
>   record with an existing document in the database. Documents that do
>   not match an existing document in the database are inserted as usual.
>   By default mongoimport matches documents based on the _id field. Use
>   --upsertFields to specify the fields to match against.

```
mongoimport -c collectionName -d databaseName  --type csv --mode merge --file CSV2
```